# How we add custom OID in Opennms

Tags: mib, opennms

I am using Opennms first time. I am having problem adding OID value to opennms. For this I have follow multiple documents.

I have added a protocol in capsd-configurations.xml, define services  in poller-configuration.xml and added monitor at the end of poller-configuration and also added in category.xml.

But I have not seen services in opennms pannel. Please help me to solve my problem. What wrong i was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from Email List. Thanks to Ghislain Hachey for this to solve my problem

If you are using the latest version, provisiond is now the default and capsd is disabled. Changes to capsd-configurations.xml won't be seen. Take a thorough look at the Web UI's Admin - Node Provisioning section. You can directly "add interfaces for scanning" which will detect all services supported out-of-the-box defined in the Provisioning Requisitions' default foreign source definition. If you wish to add custom services to be detected, a possibility is to create a new foreign source definition with that new service or simply add the new service to the default foreign source definition. This will take care of detecting the device(s) and defined services.  How data is collected afterwards is exactly like before (polling and collecting).

-- 
GH